# duration of cooldown on my poer up doesnt revert my players size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so my character /player get big but it doesn't seem to revert back to its original size after a few seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public float multiplier = 1.4f;
    public float duration = 4f;
    private bool flag;
    public GameObject pickupEffect;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if(!flag)
           StartCoroutine (Pickup(collision));
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator Pickup(Collider2D player)
    {
        flag = true;

        GameObject ps = (GameObject )Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(ps,0.2f);

        player.transform.localScale *= multiplier;


        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);





    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code provided that resets the player size, it just makes him bigger. What have you tried to make the size revert back?

Comment: ivetried adding a cooldown for the powerup but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: nevermind i fixed it by dividing the multiplier!

Comment: Then publish your answer so that others may learn from it.

Comment: Please improve your question and add your sollution. It would be a valuable contribution to our knowledge base and we will reward you with reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the size after the duration runs out.. 
I added two lines here, one stores the old localScale into `origScale`, second line resets localScale to `origScale`

```
private IEnumerator Pickup(Collider2D player)
    {
        var origScale = this.transform.localScale;
        flag = true;

        GameObject ps = (GameObject )Instantiate(pickupEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(ps,0.2f);

        player.transform.localScale *= multiplier;


        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        this.transform.localScale = origScale;
    }
```